# ideas.salesforce.com - How do we relate to it?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

SF has it's ideas site (I have a feeling everyone here had to visit there at least once). Is there a way that in answers that we answer here, there will be some special link to SF ideas links? (like we have for internal SE sites and questions?)

I have a feeling that the ideas site will have a significant presence here (much more than the SF forum).

Or should we relate to ideas site differently?

I believe a tag for it is a must btw - [ideas]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the tag is a good idea (badum-tish) but there is no need for special links beyond the native stackexchange functionality.

Most answers with a link to the idea exchange will just be: here's how you do it in apex but vote for this idea to make this native functionality.

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=badum%20tish